# Apache and video streaming: how to use HTTP apache partial content to stream a video?

Tags: apache, http

I just discovered the HTTP 206 partial content.

Can this be used to convert a simple Apache into a video streamer (so we don't have to download the whole video before we can play it) ?

I found lot of sample of nodejs/express to stream videos but I could not find any for apache.

Comment: You might be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845571/how-to-build-a-simple-video-streaming-server and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369046/http-media-streaming-server

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to your question: **yes**.

Yet the details get complicated:

1. What clients do you target? Most probably your question implicates that the video will be watched in any kind of web browser (desktop/mobile). But there's also the possibility to just use HTTP to transfer the file (by adding it up on server and repeatedly invoking `wget -c` on client, thus using 206 Partial Content) and then listen/watch to the file with another client, such as VLC Media Player or ffplay.
2. What delay is acceptable? If delay doesn't matter (e. g. 10 seconds or more), then [DASH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Adaptive_Streaming_over_HTTP) or [HSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) will make a good solution as they are supported by widely known video.js player. They are HTTP, but don't use 206 technique. If it shall be small (< 2 s, e. g. for videoconferencing), then LL-HSL or LL-DASH can be used. [This source](https://www.theoplayer.com/blog/how-does-ll-hls-work) claims that sometimes byte ranges could be used, so this could make use of 206 technique. If it shall be even smaller (e.g. 500ms, 200ms), you will most probably need a non-HTTP solution like WebRTC.